# Powershell > not every code path returns a value in the method

Tags: powershell, if-statement, return

Good Morning Folks;)

I run into a "very simple" problem, but I can not figure out what I am missing ;/

To my knowledge, I added in **every line of code a return statement**, but i keeps telling me there is one (or more) missing.

```
[string]getSamAccountName([string]$givenname, [string]$surname)
{

    $SANarray = @(

        $SANv1 = ($givenname.Substring(0, 4))
        $SANv2 = ($surname.Substring(0, 2) + $givenname.Substring(0, 2)).ToLower()
        $SANv3 = ($givenname.Substring(0, 2) + $surname.Substring(0, -2)).ToLower()
        $SANv4 = ($givenname.Substring(0, 3) + $surname.Substring(0, 1)).ToLower()
        $SANv5 = $null
    )


    foreach ($san in $SANarray)
    {
        if (get-aduser -Identity $SAN -eq $SANv1) { Write-host "SANv1 already Taken" }
        else { return [string]$SANv1 }

        if (get-aduser -Identity $SAN -eq $SANv2) { Write-host "SANv2 already Taken" }
        else { return [string]$SANv2 }

        if (get-aduser -Identity $SAN -eq $SANv3) { Write-host "SANv3 already Taken" }
        else { return [string]$SANv3 }

        if (get-aduser -Identity $SAN -eq $SANv4) { Write-host "SANv4 already Taken" }
        else { return [string]$SANv4 }

        if (get-aduser -Identity $SAN -eq $SANv5) { Write-host "No SamAccountName Availible" }
        else { return $null }


    }


}
```

I hope someone can help me and tell me what the heck im doing wrong;D

(Yes i know, its not the proper way to give out SamAccountName´s but thats how i have to do it;( )

Comment: what [_exactly_] does `keeps telling me there is one (or more) missing.` mean? [*grin*]

Comment: ;) Thank you for you fast reply! 

getSamAccountName is red underlined when i hover over it it Say: "Not every codepath returns a Value in this Method"

Comment: please add that info to your Question so folks can find it. [*grin*]

Comment: in VSCode i get red squiggles under `getSamAccountName` and the hover message is `Unexpected token 'getSamAccountName' in expression or statement.`. when i remove the leading `[string]`, the error indicator goes away. ///// i have never EVER seen anyone set a type on a function ... and you don't seem to have the required `function` prefix for it.

Comment: `[string]getSamAccountName` --> `function getSamAccountName`. Then also finalize the function with a closing `}`

Comment: It is in the title;)?

But wow. yes..OMG, this is embarrassing;D Thanks your your help mate!

Stay healthy!

Comment: If it is a function then add the function word before it. Thats missing.